# How can I get `terraform init` to run on my Apple Silicon Macbook Pro for the Google Provider?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, apple-m1

When I run `terraform init` for my Google Cloud Platform project on my Apple Silicon macbook pro I get this error.

```
Provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v3.57.0 does not have a package available for your current platform, darwin_arm64.
```

How can I work around this? I thought that the Rosetta2 emulator would check this box, but alas...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most providers already have packages available in newer versions.
You can update the provider via:
`terraform init -upgrade`
If this route is not acceptable for you or if it does not solve the problem, look at the answer below.

Build Terraform's GCP provider from scratch! I modified this walkthrough. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27257#issuecomment-754777716

```
brew install --build-from-source terraform
```

This will install Golang as well (and that appears to be working as of this post)

```
git clone https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google.git
cd terraform-provider-google
git checkout v3.22.0
go get -d github.com/pavius/impi/cmd/impi
make tools
go fmt
make build
```

The following directory probably does not already exist so lets create it and copy the binary we just built.

```
mkdir -p ${HOME}/.terraform.d/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google/3.22.0/darwin_arm64
cp ${HOME}/go/bin/terraform-provider-google ${HOME}/.terraform.d/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google/3.22.0/darwin_arm64
```

Note that `${HOME}/go` is where your golang install will be located if you don't already have `${GOPATH}` already defined. If you do, then modify the above commands to account for the location of your new build binaries.

```
cp ${GOPATH}/bin/terraform-provider-google ${HOME}/.terraform.d/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google/3.22.0/darwin_arm64
```

After going back to my project voila!

```
➜ terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/google...
- Installing hashicorp/google v3.22.0...
- Installed hashicorp/google v3.22.0 (unauthenticated)

Terraform has created a lock file .terraform.lock.hcl to record the provider
selections it made above. Include this file in your version control repository
so that Terraform can guarantee to make the same selections by default when
you run "terraform init" in the future.

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
```

Comment: This is a great! One thing to note, is that you may need to specify other providers when cloning and copying. For example: `git clone https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws.git` and `${HOME}/go/bin/terraform-provider-aws`

Comment: @DevinCairns that is covered in the GitHub issue link, but isn’t precisely relevant to the title of the post which is limited to the Google Provider.

Comment: @reka18 Thank you so much, It helped me a lot.

Comment: I get ./tools.go
You can use the command: `make fmt` to reformat code.
make: *** [fmtcheck] Error 1 and running make fmt does not fix it.

Comment: Same here. Sad. Could it be a GO version issue ?

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74477115/992887) for a simpler way to do this using `m1-terraform-provider-helper`

Answer (score 29):

Build *Terraform* from scratch by using the *tfenv* package, which can build a specific version adapted to the platform architecture.

I ran the following to install a version that works under my M1 Macbook  (version 1.3.3 in this case):

```
brew uninstall terraform
brew install tfenv
TFENV_ARCH=amd64 tfenv install 1.3.3
tfenv use 1.3.3
```

Comment: This suggestion solved my problem. I am using Macbook pro 2023. Thanks

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74477115/992887) for a simpler way to do this using `m1-terraform-provider-helper`

Comment: I still get `open ~/.terraform.d/plugins/darwin_arm64: no such file or directory` after using `tfenv` to install Terraform 1.6.5 with these exact instructions...

Comment: Absolute life saver thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Thanks for this repo: https://github.com/kreuzwerker/m1-terraform-provider-helper. This will remove the overhead of building and compiling from us.

**Usage:**

```
brew install kreuzwerker/taps/m1-terraform-provider-helper
m1-terraform-provider-helper activate # (In case you have not activated the helper)
m1-terraform-provider-helper install hashicorp/template -v v2.2.0 # Install and compile
```

This will compile the provider for our arm_64 in the location:

`~/.terraform.d/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template/2.2.0/darwin_arm64`

For this to be working, these are my findings:-

- Your Terraform version should be at least >= **1.0.2**
- You should delete the older checksums of the requested provider [template in my case] from the `.terraform.lock.hcl`

  - **or** try running `m1-terraform-provider-helper lockfile upgrade` which finds and updates these checksums
- Please change your provider and version that you need to be installed in the terraform code.

Go ahead now !!!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  `m1-terraform-provider-helper` is a great tool that really simplifies solving this problem by managing the build process and the binary provider files.  It even updates the Terraform lockfile using `m1-terraform-provider-helper lockfile upgrade`.

Answer (score 5):

OK. So, I ''found'' the answer to my problem. You most probably, like me, use the main.tf config that look like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.22.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  credentials = file("foo.json")

  project = "foo"
  region  = "us-central1"
  zone    = "us-central1-c"
}

resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
  name = "terraform-network"
}
```

Well, DROP this part, you do not need it:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.22.0"
    }
  }
}
```

If it still not working, reinstall TERRAFORM and start from a new fresh and clean directory for your project.

Hope this can help some one.

BTW, my Terraform version

**Terraform v1.1.3**
**on darwin_arm64**
**+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v4.6.0**

Comment: Thanks, this helped me sort out my env, which is the same as yours.  Regarding the provider version, it's not that "you do not need it", but rather that that the version you're requesting is not supported for your env.

After  running `terraform init`, and seeing which version is supported, I re-added the `required_providers` section with the latest version...

Comment: Thank's for that clarification update !

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
# Remove your local lock file!
rm .terraform.lock.hcl

# And then -
brew install kreuzwerker/taps/m1-terraform-provider-helper
m1-terraform-provider-helper activate
m1-terraform-provider-helper install hashicorp/template -v v2.2.0
terraform init
```

Answer (score 1):

You can list the supported provider versions by running:

```
PROVIDER="hashicorp/google"
curl --silent https://registry.terraform.io/v1/providers/${PROVIDER}/versions | jq -r '.versions[] | select(.platforms[] | contains({os: "darwin", arch: "arm64"})) | .version'
```

Then just use one of the supported versions in your `required_providers` block in the Terraform code.