# Terraform aws provider issue for Mac M1 Installation

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I use Terraform v1.0.11 on my Mac M1. When I try to run `terraform init`, I run into the following error:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/local...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/null...
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/aws from the dependency lock file
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/random...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/template...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/external...
- Installing hashicorp/external v2.1.0...
- Installed hashicorp/external v2.1.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/local v2.1.0...
- Installed hashicorp/local v2.1.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/null v3.1.0...
- Installed hashicorp/null v3.1.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/aws v3.53.0
- Installing hashicorp/random v3.1.0...
- Installed hashicorp/random v3.1.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
╷
│ Error: Incompatible provider version
│ 
│ Provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0 does not have a package available for your current platform, darwin_arm64.
│ 
│ Provider releases are separate from Terraform CLI releases, so not all providers are available for all platforms. Other versions of this provider
│ may have different platforms supported.
```

My provider provider info:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      version = "~> 3.53.0"
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that the provider version is not available for M1. Is there any workaround for this?

I tried using this: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27257#issuecomment-754777716, but with provider version 3.53.0, but running into issues.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: try 3.63.0 works for me

Comment: According to the error message, it is the `template` provider that is incompatible. Also, that provider is deprecated anyway, so you can upgrade its usage on your configs.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I am pretty new to Terraform. Can you please explain what a `template` is? I also tried changing provider version to 3.63.0 like @BrianMcCall said. But its not working.

Comment: You need to remove the `template` provider from your configuration.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Even if I remove the `template` part I am getting the same error. It shows `Provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.66.0 does not have a package available for your current platform, darwin_amd64.`

Comment: As stated in the error message, the provider is not available on your platform. You mentioned you tried the workaround of building the provider yourself but you "ran into issues" -- What issues did you run into? Maybe your question is more about how to build and use the package locally for your platform then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use what they say on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66281882/how-can-i-get-terraform-init-to-run-on-my-apple-silicon-macbook-pro-for-the-go) to run on your M1 which is to compile the resource for your architecture.

However **template** is a [deprecated resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest) and you can use [templatefile](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file) which works correctly on M1.